# Translation coordinates for a circle under a certain angle

Tags: math

I have 2 circles that collide in a certain collision point and under a certain collision angle which I calculate using this formula :

```
C1(x1,y1) C2(x2,y2)
```

and the angle between the line uniting their centre and the x axis is

```
X = arctg (|y2 - y1| / |x2 - x1|)
```

and what I want is to translate the circle on top under the same angle that collided with the other circle. I mean with the angle X and I don't know what translation coordinates should I give for a proper and a straight translation!

Comment: A picture says more than a thousand words...

Comment: Could you put a bit more structure into describing what you have got, what the formula (or function?) `C(x, y)` does, and what exactly it is you want to achieve? I don't quite get what translation you're looking for.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with OpenGL, or programming in general.  I think this should be moved to [http://programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer it probably isn't a good idea to suggest migration to sites you aren't familiar with; not least with this question, which would be a poor fit for [programmers.se]

Comment: @AakashM This isn't a poor question (to me at least), it's just not fit for this site so I decided to at least recommend it to another site that would fit it.  If it doesn't, then what site should this question be asked?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to move **C2** so that the distance between the centers is unchanged, and `X' = 0`? Or `X'= 2X`?

Answer (score 0):

For what I think you mean, here's how to do it cleanly.

Think in **vectors**.

Suppose the centre of the bottom circle has coordinates `(x1,y1)`, and the centre of the top circle has coordinates `(x2,y2)`. Then define two vectors

```
support   = (x1,y1) 
direction = (x2,y2) - (x1,y1)
```

now, the line between the two centres is fully described by the parametric representation

```
line = support + k*direction
```

with `k` any value in `(-inf,+inf)`. At the initial time, substituting `k=1` in the equation above indeed give the coordinates of the top circle. On some later time `t`, the value of `k` will have increased, and substituting that new value of `k` in the equation will give the new coordinates of the centre of the top circle.

How much `k` increases at value `t` is equal to the *speed* of the circle, and I leave that entirely up to you :)

Doing it this way, you never need to mess around with any angles and/or coordinate transformations etc. It even works in 3D (provided you add in `z`-coordinates everywhere).